# Enable Free Trial for Android Subscription on Google Play

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, google-play-console, android-inapp-purchase

I am having trouble getting Free trail for In-app subscription working. The subscription is working but every time I test (even with new devices/google account) it shows as "Starting today" (see image below, the texts are in Swedish).

I assume you do not need any code for this and everything can be setup in Google Play Console.

The structure I have is like this under My app > Products > Subscriptions:

```
- Base subscription (Per month, renewed automatically)
   - Offer - Every month (renews automatically)
     Phases:
     - Free trial (duration = 1 month)
```

The offer page looks like this:

[image]

and the Phases contains only one item which is this:

[image]

Image when testing on a brand new device:
[image]

Translating "Från och med idag" => "Starting today" in English.

What am I doing wrong? Looking at Stackoverflow post all post relate to how to programatically fetch the free-trial availability status, which I'm not interested in. I assume the native Google dialog fetches this directly from Google Play servers.

Answer (score 8):

Turns out Google just last month announced a new scheme for subscriptions.

I hade to "migrate" the Free Trial offer to make it backward compatable. Click on the three dots on the offer row and then "migrate" to make it work with the old legacy method.

Comment: it doesn't works for me (react-native)